# Причастный оборот перед существительным

Tags: пунктуация

> Сад, всё больше редея и переходя в настоящий луг, спускался к
>   *поросшей зелёным камышом и ивняком* реке.

Почему второй причастный оборот не выделен запятыми? Там же есть однородные члены. И как его нужно минимально усложнить, чтобы он требовал выделения запятыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым существительным - река, запятая не нужна. А первый не причастный оборот, а деепричастный, поэтому нужна запятая.

Comment: _А первый **причастный** оборот стоит после определяемого существительного - сад._  ???  ===  Гм... Гм...

Comment: Слава, что не так?

Comment: РЕДЕЯ и ПЕРЕХОДЯ --  ДЕЕпричастия.

Comment: А-а, действительно. Спасибо!